# Writing 2 Lists of Floats to a CSV File in Separate Columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a program that creates two very large lists of float numbers.

We can call them list_x and list_y. They look like this:

```
list_x = [0.555, 0.5552, 0.55553]
list_y = [0.152, 0.155, 0.160]
```

I want it two be stored into a csv like this:

```
Column 1  Column 2
0.555      0.152
0.5552     0.155
0.55553    0.160
```

Here is my code:

```
with open('data.csv','w', newline = '') as out:
        csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL).writerows(zip(list_x, list_y))
```

However, it prints it like this instead:

```
Column 1
0.555   0.152
0.5552  0.155
0.55553 0.160
```

And no column 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using delimiter as ' ' [delimiter=' ']. so it splits 'Column 1' itself as 'Column' and '1', two separate headers.

Comment: Or, change the delimiter to `\t`

Comment: Thanks, I just removed the delimiter and it made 2 columns, thanks! \t does not work by the way

Answer (score 1):

When I try your code, I do not get any header line.

One solution would be to explicitly add headers to the list of items to be written, e.g.,

```
headers = [("Column 1", "Column 2")]
with open('data.csv','w', newline = '') as out:
    csv.writer(out, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL).writerows(headers + zip(list_x, list_y))
```

Comment: Sorry there are no headers in the file I just wanted to show that I wanted them in 2 columns